# Evaluation differences between IF operator and If, then, else

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have come across a scenario that I did not expect and need help answering.  Our current system makes calls to SQL stored procs and as such creates SQL commands, adds the parameters and adds the values of those parameters...say for an Insert.

We had code like what is below...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyTimestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime)
If MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing Then
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = MyObject.MyTimestamp
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = Nothing
End If
```

Now, when I first saw this I was a little surprised that the MyObject.MyTimestamp ever evaluated to Nothing, but it had been there for years with no issue.  During a clean-up effort the code to add a parameter and set its value was combined and as such the code above became...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyTimestamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = If(MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing, MyObject.MyTimestamp, Nothing)
```

To me, this looked equivalent to what the code was doing originally, however that is not what was found during testing.  While testing I received a SqlTypeException:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

That is because using the If Operator evaluated the MyObject.MyTimestamp as not being Nothing, which it isn't Nothing it is DateTime.MinValue and it tried to insert it into sql and it blew up.  The way the original code was written evaluates the same Timestamp as being Nothing (not sure how/why) and does the false part.  So my question is what is the difference and should I be concerned about other datatypes...?

Comment: You should be concerned about "Option Strict Off" .. If you turn it ON, your code will show an error at `if MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing`, because it should be `IsNot` (or `Not ... Is`) and not `<>`. That wouldn't solve problems where you have a value, but the value is not in acceptable range, but thats something you have to check anyway (what about a string of 15MB that should be stored in a field of 128 bytes?)

Comment: Option Strict and Option Explicit are both set to On at the top of every code file in the application.

Comment: arg. You are right. And thats the problem. DateTime is a valuetype/structure. Those can never be "nothing". Nothing means "default value" for them. An Integer thats nothing is 0. A Double is 0.0 and a DateTime is ... 1.1.1 12:00 AM

Comment: Exactly.  From further testing I don't think it is the evaluation that is the problem `MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing` evaluates the same as `MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Datetime.MinValue`.  I think it has something to do with me setting the value of the parameter at the same time it is added.  Both the If Operator and the If, Then, Else evaluate the same in the immediate window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remembering (as I often don't) that `Nothing` is not equivalent to `null` in C#, but more like `Default(T)`, the following does not check if MyObject.MyTimestamp has been set:

```
MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing
```

But is acutally checking if it is the default datetime (DateTime.MinValue), which it presumably always is.

In addition, when you use:

```
If(MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing, MyObject.MyTimestamp, Nothing)
```

The two return types (`MyObject.MyTimestamp`, `Nothing`) have to be of the same type, so since the compiler knows `MyObject.Timestamp` should be a datetime, it converts nothing to a default datetime.

When you use this, however:

```
If MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing Then
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = MyObject.MyTimestamp
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = Nothing
End If
```

It recognises that the parameter for `"@MyTimestamp"` is of the type `SqlDbType.DateTime`, so creates the default for this. I don't know whether this is DbNull or an actual value off the top of my head, but either way it will be an allowed value so won't throw an error.

As an aside you probably want to be setting the parameter to `DbNull.Value` and not `Nothing`:

```
If MyObject.MyTimestamp <> Nothing Then
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = MyObject.MyTimestamp
Else
   cmd.Parameters.Item("@MyTimestamp").Value = DbNull.Value
End If
```

Comment: okay...that's it!  The return values from the IF Opertor being the same is what I had overlooked.  I tried using the If Operator logic but separated the add parameter and setting the parameter value and I got the same error.  And yes, I do want these as DBNull.Value as they are in other areas of the code.  Thanks...